# curl - know i reached html file from header

Tags: bash, curl

I send curl cmd from shell with --head flag:

```
curl -k --head http://www.something.com/whatever
```

is there any way to know from answer headers if this link contains html file can be shown in browser or another type of downloading file (pdf, doc, txt, etc).
Thanks.

Comment: Hey, you need to get the Content-Type of request?

Answer (score 1):

The response header should contain a `Content-Type` field,
for HTML files it should be:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

See also the [list of known MIME-types](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html).

Comment: Thanks, but i will try to clarify myself.
 I want to male sure the content is html file and can be parses as html - without parsing the file.
I can look on the doctype, but this is obvious too.
is there any idea?

Comment: @Student unless you have a particular reason to suspect the web server to misbehave, checking the `Content-Type` header as I suggested should work well in practice. But maybe your goal is different from what the question suggests. I was under the impression that you are using a `HEAD` request to avoid downloading files unnecessarily. If that's not the case, and you will download files anyway, and then need to decide whether it's valid HTML or not, that's a different question entirely. In which case I suggest to post a new, clearer question.